# Adding a settings page inside my app (Xcode and Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, settings

I want to add a settings page within my app.
I have seen that there is a way to have a settings page (settings bundle) inside the native Settings app (like here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html). But I want to have the settings for my app, within my app.

I could do a couple of things, but I don't know which is the right approach... I could use the InAppSettingsKit (http://www.inappsettingskit.com/) or do everything manually which would be very messy(I think?) What have you guys/girls done with your settings in the past, and what do you think would be the best approach to this? And is there a better approach to this problem, than what I have listed above?

Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 9):

Depending the number of parameters you need in your settings, the approach could be different.

- If you have **a lot of parameters**, with the need of rows containing sliders, switches or whatever advanced cell configuration, then using a library such as [InAppSettingsKit](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit) is a good bet.
- On the other hand, if you have only **a few parameters**, using `UITableViewController` with `Static Cells` and `Grouped Style` could be sufficient. You can do a lot of things in `Interface Builder` and perform actions in code.

Choose the approach you're most comfortable with, I think both are respectable.